# Redis batch remove members from different sets

Tags: redis, batch-processing

New to Redis; Is there a way to remove members from different sets all at once? I'm guessing you would have to find them all first and then remove them, is that possible without multiple calls?

thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to reduce the number of calls or perform the removal atomically? Do you know the target Sets and members?

Comment: Really to reduce the number of calls, atomic would be nice but not necessary. I know the target sets, I have a list of members which may or may not be in a set.